# Ubuntu 10.10 installed from windows 7: how to expand drive?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, wubi

I'm new to Linux. I've installed Ubuntu 10.10 from Windows 7. It's not in Virtual PC, it is independent. It uses a virtual drive in `c:`, I have chosen it to be 10 Gb.

Now I want to increase the size of this drive. How to do this? I've configured the system for PHP MySQL and installed a lot of software and fixed wireless connection problems a lot of things i don't want to loose these things and start troubling again.

I heard of backups, but I think it will take too long. Is there any other simple and fast way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words, you're using Wubi, right? As far as I know, it is currently not possible to resize a Wubi installation of Ubuntu 10.04 or 10.10.

What you can do is add another virtual disk and mount it on `/home` or `/srv`, wherever you need room. There are instructions in the [Wubi guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How%20do%20I%20resize%20the%20virtual%20disks?). In a nutshell: download the [`wubi-add-virtual-disk`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=wubi-add-virtual-disk) script, and run the following command in a terminal (the number is the size of the new virtual disk):

```
sudo sh wubi-add-virtual-disk /srv 20000
```

I recommend moving your installation to a real partition. It'll be less hassle in the long term. In your situation, the route I recommend is:

1. Boot an Ubuntu 10.10 installation CD/USB, and perform a quick installation on a separate partition. Don't bother configuring anything.
2. Boot your existing Wubi installation. Mount your new direct-to-partition installation. Let's call the mount point `/media/new`. Open a terminal and run the following commands to overwrite the new partition with your existing data from the Wubi installation, and set up the bootloader for the new partition.

   ```
   cd /media/new
   cp etc/fstab /var/tmp/fstab.new
   rm -rf *
   sudo cp -ax / .
   chroot .
   update-grub
   grub-install /dev/sda
   ```
3. Open both `/media/new/etc/fstab` and `/var/tmp/fstab.new` in an editor. In each file, there is a line with a single `/` in the second column. Replace the line in `/media/new/etc/fstab` with the one from `/var/tmp/fstab.new`.
4. Reboot. You should now be in the new installation. Make sure everything is ok, then you can remove the Wubi files on the Windows partition.

Keep a bootable Ubuntu CD/USB at hand, in case something goes wrong.

Whatever you do, **make backups**. Making backups is the only way not to lose data.